# create an arbitrary instance of a class with xUnit to function as a stub

Tags: .net, xunit

Is there anyway to generate a instance of a class on-the-fly in xUnit to function as a stub?

Something like:

`var myInstanceToTest = Xunit.DummyInstance<MyClassToTest>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible. xUnit is a library for creating unit tests, it's not designed for mocking or stubbing. But you could use Moq for that: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/